# cp file to a directory with a file with same name

Tags: linux, cp

Sorry if I missed something in the `cp` manual, but is there a way to copy a file to a directory where there may be a file with the same name? Something like adding a postfix to the name of the copied file if there is a file with the same name on the destination directory. Something like:

```
ls foo
    file
cp file foo/
ls foo
    file
    file*
```

The OS, that I am running, is Ubuntu Gnu/Linux.

Comment: you *want* the postfix added if/when there's a file with the same name?

Comment: yes, like a star or anything. Edited

Comment: For there to be a good answer, I think you should settle on what you want :)

Comment: Also let us know whether you're on a Linux system or some other Unix. GNU `cp` has built-in support for backing existing files up (yes, that's not exactly what you want to do, but it's there).

Comment: Edited. Thanks for feedbacks as a new user of this Forum. Will read advices for newcommers :)

Comment: GNU `cp` -- which is standard on Ubuntu -- has a `--backup` option which allows for the opposite, i.e. renaming the original so that you can copy in a file with its original name.

Comment: and if there's already a `file*` in the destination...?

Comment: I mould avoid using a `*` as the post-fix. It will lead to many troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a positive integer to the target name if the name is already taken, and also incrementing that integer until a free name is found:

```
mycp () {
    local source="$1"
    local target="$2"

    local n

    # If the target pathname is a directory, add the source filename
    # the end of it.
    if [ -d "$target" ]; then
        target+="/$(basename "$source")"
    fi

    # Increment n until a free name is found
    # (this may leave n unset if the source filename is free).
    while [ -e "$target$n" ]; do
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
    done

    cp "$source" "$target$n"
}
```

Note: This function does not take any other arguments than a source and target pathname. It also assumes that you are using the `bash` shell.

To "install" it, just run the above code in your shell, or add it to wherever you usually add aliases and functions.

Testing:

```
$ ls
dir file
$ ls dir/
```

```
$ mycp file dir
$ ls dir/
file
```

```
$ mycp file dir
$ ls dir/
file    file1
```

```
$ mycp file dir
$ ls dir/
file    file1   file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own function.  This will keep adding underscores until there is not a duplicate:

```
mycp() {
    if [[ -f "$2" ]]; then
        mycp "$1" "${2}_"
    else
        cp "$1" "$2"
    fi
}
```

Not compatible with passing arguments (e. g. `cp -p`).  The better option is to use `cp -n`, which will not overwrite an existing file.